# How to set current ImageView Image as WallPpaper using ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview, android-imageview, android-wallpaper

I am having an Application Containing Different Images using ImageView and ViewPager. I want to set the current image shown through ImageView as Wallpaper.

But it only makes the first image as wallpaper and remaining images when I tried to set as wallpaper it makes the mobile screen black (means it makes wallpaper black) it does not set other images from ImageView as Wallpaper.

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.testimagesbaby.BabyBoys"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_baby_boys"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/viewPager">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java File:**

```
public class BabyBoys extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    private AlertDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby_boys);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter= new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);


    }

    public static Bitmap viewToBitmap (View view, int width, int height){
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas= new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_boys_tab, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_setwall) {
            setwall(); }
        else if (id == R.id.action_save) {

            }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setwall()
    {

        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(viewToBitmap(viewPager, viewPager.getWidth(),viewPager.getHeight()));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sucessfully Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
 }
```

**ViewPagerAdapter File**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer [] images= {R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4,R.drawable.b5,R.drawable.b6,R.drawable.b7,R.drawable.b8,R.drawable.b9,R.drawable.b10,R.drawable.b11};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;


    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);


        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[+position]);
        ViewPager vp= (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view,0);
        return view;

    }
    @Override
    public  void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        ViewPager vp= (ViewPager) container;
        View view= (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the current image to the wallpaper manager.

Do the following changes

1. Define your images[] in BabyBoys activity
2. Get the current position of the viewPager in setWall function
   int currentImagePos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
3. Rather than

`wallpaperManager.setBitmap(viewToBitmap(viewPager,viewPager.getWidth(),viewPager.getHeight()));`

use

`myWallpaperManager.setResource(images[currentImagePos]);`

Comment: I remove the + sign, but the problem still exists (no change before or after removing the + sign. Kindly help me out please. ANUJ GUPTA

Comment: Kindly help me out

Comment: Very Much Helpful, Thanks :) Needful Work Done. My Problem is Solved.

Comment: ANUJ GUPTA "Kindly Help me out in this question too"  https://stackoverflow.com/q/46658642/8727122   I will be very Thankful.